# Bug nas revisões

Tags: bug, status-pronto, histórico-de-revisões

Ao verificar a revisão [**desta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/114391/revisions), há 3 opções de visualizar as revisões, e se alternar entre essas opções que são os botões <kbd>alinhado</kbd>, depois <kbd>lado a lado</kbd> e depois <kbd>markdown lado a lado</kbd>, o link "completa" fica se duplicado.

E quanto mais se alterna, mais ele se multiplica, como pode ser visto no print:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Yikes! Investigando, dou um retorno em breve

Answer (score 7):

Oops! Este bug foi corrigido e estará disponível na próxima build pra produção.

Esse link especificamente (`completa`) só fica visível caso a edição visualizada seja muito grande, dentre outras condições. O controle pra mostrar/esconder o link incluía essa linha de código:

```
if (menuDiv.find("a:last").text() !== "full")
```

Essa lógica só iria funcionar pro SOen, onde o texto do link é de fato `"full"`. Pra consertar, bastou substituir essa linha por:

```
if (menuDiv.find("a:last").text() !== "completa")
```

...

**BRINKS!** Alterei o JS pra não mais usar o texto do link como referência, e sim algo mais seguro. No caso, os links agora serão anotados com a classe `.full-link`, e a linha acima mudou para:

```
if (skipped.length && !menuDiv.find("a:last").hasClass("full-link"))
```

Obrigada por reportar esse erro erro erro erro! <3

Comment: Bacana, e olha que eu quase acreditei no `if (menuDiv.find("a:last").text() !== "full")` hehe xD

Comment: @DiegoF na verdade eu acho que era feito assim sim, só que ela consertou bem consertado, e não apenas trocou o "full" por "completa" :P

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta resposta resposta resposta! :P